# How can I pass VM args to applicationContext in spring

Tags: spring, applicationcontext, vmargs

How can I pass `vm args` *(java -Dport = 5)* to the `application context`?

I want to configure the port *dynamically* by the user, using the `application context`.

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1

Answer (score 2):

In case you trying to access the VM arguments in spring application context, then just add the below bean definition in context file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

And access the VM args as ${vm_property}.

e.g if you passed the –Dport=5, which can be accessed as

```
<bean class="com.testing.test.MyClass">  
  <property name="myProperty" value="${port}"></property>  
</bean>
```

Comment: Since the answer worked, can you please accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think There is only one way in spring using injection. and get the property value from any property file